# Get the diffrence between two lists in python and print it if they have same value

Tags: python

if i repeat the value it do not print it Here IS the Code to Know What i Mean

```
n=[1,1,1]
n2=[1,1]
for number in n:
    if number not in n2:
    print number
```

i do not get any output i want it to print 1 how can i do that i am a beginner in python help me it work only if i change the value of number like

```
n=[1,1,1,2]
n2=[1,1]
for number in n:
    if number not in n2:
     print number # here it print 2 but i want to print the one too
```

how can i do that

Comment: If `n1 = [1,1,2,2]` and `n2 = [2,2,1,1]` want would your desired result be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've basically told Python to print what ISN'T in the list not what is in it.

```
n=[1,1,1]
n2=[1,1]
for number in n:
    if number not in n2:
        print number
```

Where you've written `if number not in n2:`, change it to `if number in n2:` then it should print whatever value which occurs in n and n2.

Also, your indentations are wrong(probably caused when you were trying to pass your code here) and you've missed the parentheses. Try this:

```
n=[1,1,1]
n2=[1,1]
for number in n:
    if number in n2:
        print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n=[1,1,1]
n2=[1,1]

# for each number in n2
for number in n2:

    # if it also exists in n
    if number in n:

        # remove it from n
        n.remove(number)

# now print whatever is left over in n
print n
```